# Emacs doesn't recognize Ctrl+2 in a terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

Emacs version is 24.5.1, terminal is Mintty 1.1.3.

When I press <kbd>C-2</kbd> in Emacs it produces `M-[ 5 0 ; 5 u` key which is very strange because <kbd>C-1</kbd> behaves as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "ctrl-2 is OK"? It's not part of the plain ASCII character set, so it must be sent using escape characters, the question is why doesn't Emacs understand them. What's the value of `TERM`?

Comment: @Lindydancer my term is xterm-256color, thanks.

Comment: (Workaround: If you are trying to use `C-2` to pass a numerical prefix arg of 2, you can use `M-2` or `C-u 2` or `ESC 2` instead.)

Comment: @Drew thanks, but I want press C-2 to call set-mark-command.